# iterate through more than one vector using a for loop

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to check the size of different vectors by iteration using a for loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> V1;
vector<int> V2;
vector<int> V3;

for (int i=0;i<3;i++){ 
    cout<<Vi.size()<<endl;
}
```

Unfortunately i don't know if it's possible to iterate through vector names and if it is, how to write the parameter i such that my compiler knows that it is the integer of my loop.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider making an array or vector of vectors (nested array). Otherwise macros have to be involved

Comment: How about `for (auto* v : {&V1, &V2, &V3}) { cout << v->size() << endl; }`? [Demo](https://ideone.com/6wf6Wo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're attempting to do in that specific way, aka evaluating `i` into its value for the variable name in `Vi.size()`, because the compiler evaluates this to a variable named `Vi` which doesn't exist. However, as others have pointed out you can do this differently but still get the same result, here are a few examples:

Credit to @kerrek-sb for this one (probably the best option):

```
for (auto* v : {&V1, &V2, &V3}) { std::cout << v->size() << std::endl; }
```

Using an array (downside: to add more vectors you have to use dynamic allocation and copying; upside: simple for your purposes as shown):

```
const int size = 3;  // Or whatever size you want
// needs to be const because c++11 and up don't support variable length arrays(VLAs)
std::vector<int> V[size];
V[0].push_back(0);  // Appends integer to vector
V[0].push_back(10);
V[1].push_back(1);
V[2].push_back(2);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    std::cout << V[i].size() << std::endl;
}  // OUTPUT:
   // 2
   // 1
   // 1
```

Using an array of pointers to already created vectors(downside: you have to use dynamic allocation to change the size of the array; upside: you can pass vectors into a function and access them like this:

```
const int size = 3;
std::vector<int> V1(10);  // Create three vectors of different sizes
std::vector<int> V2(12);
std::vector<int> V3(14);
std::vector<int> *V[size];  // Create an array of 3 vector<int> pointers
V[0] = &V1;  // Set each element to it's corresponding vector
V[1] = &V2;
V[2] = &V3;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    std::cout << V[i]->size() << std::endl;
}  // OUTPUT:
   // 10
   // 12
   // 14
```

Using a vector of vectors (upside: you can `push_back`(append) as many vector's as you'd like after creation):

```
int size = 3;  // Or whatever size you want
std::vector<std::vector<int>> V(0);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    V.push_back(std::vector<int>((i+1)*2)); // (0+1)*2; (1+1)*2; (2+2)*2
}
for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << V[i].size() << std::endl;
}  // OUTPUT:
   // 2
   // 4
   // 6
```

You could also do a vector of pointers to vector's which would give you both the variable size of a vector and the ability to pass in vectors that are already created from other places.